# $lookup multi-level nesting array of objects in mongodb4.0

Tags: mongodb

this is my local document
**Class**

```
{
    "_id":1,
    "array1": [{
        "name": "chenzhe",
        "_id": "1-1",
        "array1": [{
            "_id": "1-1-1",
            "name": "fbb",
            "nest_nest_array": [{
                "name": "ym",
                "_id": "1-1-1-1"
            },
            {
                "name": "ym",
                "_id": "1-1-1-2"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "gw",
        "_id": "1-2",
        "nestArray": [{
            "_id": "1-2-1",
            "name": "fbb",
            "nest_nest_array": [{
                "name": "ym",
                "_id": "1-2-1-1"
            }]
        }]
    }
]
}
```

this is foreign collection documents
**Person**

```
{
  _id:"1",
  name:"chenzhe"
}
{
 _id:"2",
 name:"gw"
}
{
_id:"3",
name:"fbb"
},
{
 _id:"4",
 name:"ym"
}
```

my document have multi-level nest array of objects . I want to `$lookup pipeline` another collection. The results are in their respective arrays

UPDATE:
What I do now is use **$unwind** first. then use **$lookup pipeline**.then use **$addFields**

```
{
  "array1.array1.array1.foreignarray":"$nest_nest_Array",
  "array1.array1.foreignarray":"$nest_Array",
  "array1.foreignarray":"$array"
}
```

But I don't know how to assemble the documents back like

```
{
    "_id":1,
    "array1": [{
        "name": "chenzhe",
        "_id": "1-1",
        "foreignArray":[
            {
                "_id":"1",
                "name":"chenzhe"
            }
        ],
        "array1": [{
            "_id": "1-1-1",
            "name": "fbb",
            "foreignArray":[{
                "_id":"3",
                "name":"fbb"
            }],
            "array1": [{
                "name": "ym",
                "_id": "1-1-1-1",
                "foreignArray":[
                    {
                        "_id":"4",
                        "name":"ym"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "ym",
                "_id": "1-1-1-2",
                "foreignArray":[
                    {
                        "_id":"4",
                        "name":"ym"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[{$unwind: {
  path: "$array1",
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$array1.nestArray",
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$array1.nestArray.nest_nest_array",
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'nestArray1',
  let:{array1Name:"$array1.nestArray.nest_nest_array.name"},
  pipeline:[
    {"$match":{
      "$expr":{
        "$eq":["$$array1Name","$name"]
      }
    }}
    ],
    as:"nest_nest_Array"
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'nestArray1',
  let:{array2Name:"$array1.nestArray.nestName"},
  pipeline:[{
    "$match":{
      "$expr":{
        "$eq":["$$array2Name","$name"]
      }
    }
  }],
  as:"nest_Array"
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'nestArray1',
  let:{array3Name:"$array1.name"},
  pipeline:[{
    "$match":{
      "$expr":{
        "$eq":["$$array3Name","$name"]
      }
    }
  }],
  as:"array"
}}, {$addFields: {
  "array1.nestArray.nest_nest_array.foreignarray":"$nest_nest_Array",
  "array1.nestArray.foreignarray":"$nest_Array",
  "array1.foreignarray":"$array"
}}, {$group: {
  _id: "$array1.nestArray._id",
  nest_Array:{$push:"$array1.nestArray.nest_nest_array"},
  root:{"$push":"$$ROOT"}
}}, {$addFields: {
  "root.array1.nestArray.nest_nest_array":"$nest_Array"
}}, {$replaceRoot: {
  newRoot: {$arrayElemAt:["$root",0]}
}}, {$group: {
  _id: "$array1._id",
  nest_Array:{$push:"$array1.nestArray"},
  root:{"$push":"$$ROOT"}
}}, {$addFields: {
  "root.array1.nestArray":"$nest_Array"
}}, {$replaceRoot: {
  newRoot: {$arrayElemAt:["$root",0]}
}}, {$group: {
  _id: "$_id",
  nest_Array:{$push:"$array1"},
  root:{"$push":"$$ROOT"}
}}, {$addFields: {
  "root.array1":"$nest_Array"
}}, {$replaceRoot: {
  newRoot: {$arrayElemAt:["$root",0]}
}}, {$project: {
  array:0,
  "nest_Array":0,
  "nest_nest_Array":0
}}]
```